# Expected literal value at character 0 of

Tags: java, json

I am having the following error when trying to add records to a json file from a form:

> org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of /storage/emulated/0/Json/Prueba.json

The code I use for that is the following:

```
String ruta2 = "/storage/emulated/0/Json/Prueba.json";

k1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
k2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
k3 = edittext3.getText().toString();

try {
    JSONArray arreglo = new JSONArray(ruta2);
    JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();
    objeto.put("K1", k1);
    objeto.put("K2", k2);
    objeto.put("K3", k3);
    arreglo.put(objeto);
    ruta2 = arreglo.toString().trim();
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I already enabled the permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE_INTERNAL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```

I keep getting the same error

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: `new JSONArray(String)` expects the JSON content, not the file name.

Comment: You need to pull the JSON array FROM the `ruta2` file not give it the file directely. So you need to do a simple file read.

Comment: Change the line of code to this form:

```
JSONArray arreglo = new JSONArray(FileUtil.readFile(ruta2));
```

I don't get an error but it doesn't update the records either